# Investigate whether the sequence of functions $(f_n)$ defined by $f_n=\frac{nx^3}{7+nx^2}$ is uniformly convergent as follows.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

For any $n \in \Bbb N$, let $f_n:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a function defined by
$$f_n(x)=\frac{nx^3}{7+nx^2}, \quad \forall x \in \Bbb R.$$
Investigate whether the sequence $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent on $\Bbb R$.

**attempt:**
I've shown that
$f_n \to f$ on $\Bbb R$, where $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is a function defined by
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0, \quad x=0 \\
x, \quad x\ne 0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Notice that for any $n \in \Bbb N$ and for any $x \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$, we have
$$\frac{x^2}{(7+nx^2)^2} < \frac{x^2}{7+nx^2} < \frac{x^2}{nx^2} \implies \frac{|x|}{7+nx^2}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$$
I claimed that $(f_n)$ is converges uniformly on $\Bbb R$ to $f$. To this end, let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Choose $K \in \Bbb N$ with $K>\frac{49}{\epsilon^2}$ such that for any $n \in \Bbb N$ with $n \ge K$, we have
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)| = \left|\frac{nx^3}{7+nx^2}-x \right| = \frac{7|x|}{7+nx^2} < \frac{7}{\sqrt{n}} \le \frac{7}{\sqrt{K}}< \epsilon,$$
for any $x \in \Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$.
Hence, $(f_n)$ is converges uniformly on $\Bbb R$ to $f. \qquad \Box$

Does it correct? On the other hand, I think if the sequence of functions converges to a piecewise function, then the sequence is not uniformly convergent. I confusing on it. What's is the correct approach? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: note that $f$ is continuous

Comment: @ling So? Does it correct or not?

Comment: I think it is correct. No need for f to be piece-wise defined. f(x) = x.

Comment: Your approach is correct .